# JMeter Table Result Created 3 Timestamps

Tags: java, automation, csv, jmeter, stress-test

I am new to JMeter and Automation Test, and I have a problem in reading JMeter results in CSV. I tried running a test plan with the following Thread Group Properties:
[My JMeter Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqRgb.png)

Number of Threads: 1,
Ramp-Up Period: 1,
Loop Count: 1,
So it means that only 1 user per second will hit the web server (correct me if I'm wrong).

And my Save Configurations is like this:
[Config JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SemW7.png)

The thing is, when I open my CSV Result file, there are 3 timestamps line and I don't understand what it means.
[CSV Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKinA.png)

I thought it supposed to create 1 timestamps, since there is only 1 user.

Please let me know how to interpret this CSV Result, and how to fix it so that there's only 1 timestamp. Thank you.